# Circular dependency in spring beanfactory

Tags: spring

What are the pitfalls of using Circular dependency in Spring bean factory?
For example making bean factory A depend on B and B depend on A?

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this?

Comment: @Tichodroma I know we avoid doing it. But I have a case where It can be useful. Before deciding I just wanted to get some views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create circular dependencies with setters, or fields, then there is really not that much of a problem. If initialization depends on these dependencies, then init must be done after all beans are constructed and injected.

If they are constructor-injected, then it is pretty obviously not really possible to create the resulting objects. However, as e.g. Guice does, you can anyway, by injecting a "shell" proxy to one of the beans: When constructing A which needs B, you hack up an empty pass-through-proxy of B, and inject that. Then you construct B, giving it the proper A. Then you go back to the proxy and put B into the proxy. So now you have not the real B, but a proxy of B, in A. This might or might not be a problem. I tend to dislike this, finding the result unpredictable. *(Bob "crazybob" Lee, which created Guice with its annotation-based configuration (which ended up as JSR 330, which Spring now also implements), did that choice, and regrets it.)*

Also, circular dependencies points towards bad architecture. You should be able to construct the entire code graph without circles: The dependency-graph should be a DAG - a Directed Acyclic Graph. And you should get an error when violating this! (However, the injector must obviously try to sort out the DAG and then start with the leaf nodes, going upwards. Guice don't do that at all, even when you turn on "don't use proxies", so you randomly get proxies or not proxies even when you shouldn't need it. And if you turn on that option, it just randomly throws, making the option absolutely worthless..